# problem facing in javascript function returning value

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two javascript functions. from `validateSearchStirng()` i am calling `checkSolrServerAvailibility()`, from which i am expecting to return `flag=1` if ajax request is successful otherwise `flag=0`. but each time `checkSolrServerAvailibility()` returning flag=0. Why so and what i need to do for getting correct result

```
 function validateSearchStirng(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage)
    {
         var serverflag;
serverflag=checkSolrServerAvailibility(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL);
         if(serverflag==0)
         {
        var msg= "<hr /><font size="+size+" ><b>Solr Server Not Runing </b></font><hr /> ";
        removeList();
        $("#result").html(msg); 
         }  
         if(serverflag==1)
         {
           getSolrResponse(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL);  
         }

    }


 function checkSolrServerAvailibility(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL)
    {
        var start=itemPerPage*(showPage-1);
        var end=itemPerPage;
        var flag=0
        $.ajax({
            url: solrURL+"/solr/db/select/?qt=dismax&wt=json&&start="+start+"&      rows="+end+"&q="+query+"&json.wrf=?",
            async:true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json){
            flag=1;
                return(flag);
            }
        })
       return(flag);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
async : false
```

You should turn this flag to false.

Then you will get the desired results

Answer (score 0):

You should probably forget about using JS functions this way and do it using callbacks. So basically instead of doing something like that:

```
serverflag=checkSolrServerAvailibility(...);
```

do something like that:

```
var processServerFlagCallback = function(flag){
    // do something with your flag
}

checkSolrServerAvailibility(..., processServerFlagCallback);
```

and inside `checkSolrServerAvailability`, when you have information about success, invoke given callback with `1` as parameter, and in case of error - with `0` as parameter.

To see how to determine that an error occured during request, please see [jQuery's .ajax() documentation on `error` parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Tadeck: would you please elaborate it more what i exactly need to do to get the required result.

Comment: @Romi: You can see more information how to use callbacks eg. within presentation of Ryan Dahl, and introduction to Node.js: http://youtu.be/jo_B4LTHi3I?t=47m36s Although this is something slightly different from your application (Node.js happens on server side), the usage of basics is identical.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redesign your solution to something like

```
function checkSolrServerAvailibility(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL, success, error){
     $.ajax({
            url: "",
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(json){
                success.apply(this, arguments);
            },
            error:function(){
                error.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        })
}

function onAvailabilityCheck(json, textStatus, jqXHR){
    getSolrResponse(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL);  
}

function onAvailabilityCheckError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    var msg= "<hr /><font size="+size+" ><b>Solr Server Not Runing </b></font><hr /> ";
    removeList();
    $("#result").html(msg); 
}

function validateSearchStirng(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage){
         checkSolrServerAvailibility(sort,order,itemPerPage,showPage,query,solrURL, onAvailabilityCheck, onAvailabilityCheckError);
}
```

Since you are working with ajax request which by definition asynchronous in nature, your code will not work because once the client sent the ajax request to server it will not wait for the server response to comeback. It will keep executing the next lines... that means your flag will always be set to false.

To solve this problem my suggestion will be is to use callback methods to handle both success and failure cases as shown.

In the case of a successful ajax request the `onAvailabilityCheck` method will be called with the given parameters and if the ajax request is a failure the `onAvailabilityCheckError` method will be called.

Comment: what is error.apply(this, arguments); here what i need to pass as the arguments

Comment: `apply` is a method of calling a function with a set of parameters. ref http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=829

Comment: ` error.apply(this, arguments)` means call the function `error` with the `this` keyword inside the `error` method pointing to the same object that is pointed by the `this` keyword in the calling method and pass the parameters passed to the calling method to the called method in the same order.

Comment: `arguments` is again a system defined array like variable which holds all the parameters passed into the method, ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Comment: I did exactly as u said but i am getting the error: missing } after property list
error:function(){

Comment: Arun P Johny: will your solution call getSolrResponse() in case of success and will generate a message in case of error, or i need to do something with arguments in error.apply()